# Mac terminal error

Tags: macos, terminal, compiler-errors, vi, lex

I am trying to execute a `lex` and `yacc` program using `vi` editor on the `macbook` terminal. However while compiling with command:

```
$ gcc lex.yy.c -o rvr
```

I get the errorld:

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why this error happening??

Comment: You've left out the actual error message; the lines you've included are the summary. Please post the *entire* output of the `gcc` invocation, not just the last two lines.

Comment: If your project includes both scanner and parser, you cannot compile an executable with only the parser.